# Integers under multiplication a closed operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm watching YouTube videos to teach myself some abstract algebra, a woman claims that integers under multiplication has a closed operation. But I don't understand why.

For example: $$7x = 3$$

The 3rd element is not an integer.

Please advise

Comment: Under multiplication, not under division.

Comment: It means that if $a$ and $b$ are integers then so is $a \cdot b$.

Comment: It means that when we multiply to integers, we get an integer.

Comment: In other words, $\mathbb{Z} \cdot \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$ :-).

Comment: But if one multiplies by the inverse the 3rd element is a fraction not an integer? Apologies, first timer to this way of thinking.

Comment: Very few integers have inverses in the integers...

Comment: Then that means an integer may not have an integer multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Embarressing, I understand now.

Comment: Compare to addition, which is closed under the integers, *and* every integer has an additive inverse. Multiplication is closed, but only $1$ and $-1$ have inverses.

Comment: Don't be. We all struggle with something.

Comment: @copper.hat To be pedantic, we want $\mathbb{Z} \cdot \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z},$ not necessarily $\mathbb{Z} \cdot \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$ :)

Comment: @Stahl: I understand, but the goal was to nudge the OP not be exactly correct.

Comment: @copper.hat I understand! I had no doubt that you know what closure precisely means, I'm just poking some pedantic fun. :^)

Answer (score 1):

Closure (under multiplication) means: "An integer times an integer is also an integer". It does *not* mean:

"An integer times something else which results in an integer, means that something else is also an integer."

This is pretty obvious to see:

$2\cdot \frac{1}{2} = 1$.

Here, $2$ is an integer, and the "something else" is $\frac{1}{2}$. Our product is an integer, but it is *not* the case that we can conclude $\frac{1}{2}$ is an integer; in fact, it is not.

It can be proven that $\Bbb N$ is closed under multiplication (hint: use induction), and using the rules, for $a,b \in \Bbb N$:

$a(-b) = (-a)b = -ab\\
(-a)(-b) = ab$

(If you do not consider $0$ to be a natural number, you have a few more cases to consider, but these are easy)

it is easy to see that if $\Bbb N$ is closed under multiplication, so is $\Bbb Z$.

Perhaps this will be easier to process when you see the differences between rings, and fields. What often throws people off-guard in thinking about this, is that ordinary high-school arithmetic typically takes place in the field of rational numbers, where the *non-zero* numbers are closed under multiplication, and the equation:

$7x = 3$ has a *rational* solution, even though it is an *integral* equation.